# facebook-token and loopback passport component

Tags: facebook, passport.js, loopbackjs

I'm trying to use loopback-component-passport. It all works fine with the default strategies. But now I'm trying to use facebook-**token** strategy, which is not the same as facebook strategy.

I want to bypass the whole oauth2 stuff and just get all the benefits of this component but with a token already obtained from Facebook.

Is this possible?